# Executing grunt commands via .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, gruntjs

I am using grunt (javascript Task runner) for my web development build process. Included are things like tests with jasmine, code checking with plato, documentation (YUIdoc) and so on...

To make things a bit more convenient (and also to include this build process into another build process later) I tried to create a simple .net (C#) application that is able to execute the grunt commands and then outputs the results into a textbox. As I can always execute the grunt commands easily via the cmd-Window I tried utilizing **System.Diagnostics.Process** with **cmd.exe** to do that. Here is what I tried (for generating the code documentation):

```
private void documentationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C grunt doc";
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\myProjectFolder\\";
    p.Start();

    p.WaitForExit();
    rtbOut.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

First thing which is weired: I am getting this output:

```
>Loading "requirejs.js" tasks...
```

Yes, I do use require.js inside my project but this has nothing to do with documentation. This is the output I usually get and I would expect:

```
>Running "doc" task
>
>Running "yuidoc:compile" (yuidoc) task
>Start YUIDoc compile...
>Scanning: ../someFolder/
>Output: ../release/Documentation/
>YUIDoc compile completed in 0.968 seconds
```

And the documentation is not generated of course. But there is a *data.json* File which is generated in the correct folder but it is empty. So at least it appears that it started correctly but could not continue(?) I also tried with other tasks but none of them work using a Process in C#.

Comment: Not sure about the behavior, but why do you run grunt via cmd and not directly? It's a command line tool after all (provided that you installed the grunt-cli package).

Comment: I tried using "grunt" as Filename but it cannot find it (The System cannot find the file specified) and I don't think there really is a "grunt.exe" or so. It is somehow run via node.exe. To be honest I dont know how this works internally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem I answer my own question as I found a solution now that works for me.

I am simply doing a 'detour' now using PowerShell scripts. There is a nice article about how you can run PowerShell from C# here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Included in the System.Management.Automation there is the class Runspace which can be used to call PowerShell scripts. Now in my case such a 'script' is not more than this:

```
grunt build
```

You get back some escape codes for coloring the output which you can remove by calling it like:

```
grunt --no-color build
```